# Recipient filtering not working on Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

I have a problem with filtering on my Exchange 2010 server. This used to work fine but I am aware of no changes that would make it stop. But it did. It accepts everything now. Blocking messages addressed to "non-existent" addresses does not work. In troubleshooting this, I even specified an address to block but it's not getting blocked.

SETTINGS

(Powershell commands taken from: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125187.aspx)

```
Get-RecipientFilterConfig | Format-List Enabled
Enabled : True

Get-RecipientFilterConfig | Format-List ExternalMailEnabled
ExternalMailEnabled : True

Get-RecipientFilterConfig | Format-List InternalMailEnabled
InternalMailEnabled : True

Get-RecipientFilterConfig | Format-List BlockListEnabled
BlockListEnabled : True

Get-RecipientFilterConfig | Format-List BlockedRecipients
BlockedRecipients : {fake1@mydomain.com}

Get-RecipientFilterConfig | Format-List RecipientValidationEnabled
RecipientValidationEnabled : True
```

TELNET RESULTS

```
220 EXCH1 Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 31 Jan 2017 12:13:31 -08
00
helo test1
250 EXCH1 Hello [192.168.30.107]
mail from: fake@fake.com
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
rcpt to: fake1@mydomain.com
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
data
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
text
.
250 2.6.0 <9eac61a5-fd59-489f-9bc2-84fcf2ec25d9@EXCH1.local> [InternalId=342753] Queued mail for delivery
```

What am I missing or not checking?

Answer (score 0):

This article details exactly my issue but the suggestions there did not help. However, the two comments below said they had to recreate the Receive Connector with the same settings and that resolved it.
http://www.adnsolutions.com/exchange-recipient-filtering-not-working/
So I tried this and yes indeed, it fixed it.